# Selecting total of child records in their respective parent records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, hierarchy

I have a table of chart of account with parent child relationship (hierarchy model).
the table carry two types of accounts control accounts and transactional accounts.

Transactional accounts have balances while they do not carry any child account.

Control accounts do not have their own balances but they carry child accounts.

---

```
AccountID|     Title      |AccountType|ParentID| Balance
---------|----------------|-----------|--------|---------
 1       | Assets         |     c     |  null  | null 
 1-1     | Current Assets |     c     |  1     | null
 1-1-1   | Cash           |     t     |  1-1   | 1000
 1-1-2   | Inventory      |     t     |  1-1   | 2000
 1-2     | Fixed Assets   |     c     |  1     | null
 1-2-1   | Furniture      |     t     |  1-2   | 1500
 1-2-2   | Building       |     t     |  1-2   | 3000
```

---

i need a result set like :

---

```
AccountID|     Title      |AccountType|ParentID| Balance
---------|----------------|-----------|--------|---------
 1       | Assets         |     c     |  null  | 7500 --sum of current and fixed Assets
 1-1     | Current Assets |     c     |  1     | 3000 --sum of cash and inventory
 1-1-1   | Cash           |     t     |  1-1   | 1000
 1-1-2   | Inventory      |     t     |  1-1   | 2000
 1-2     | Fixed Assets   |     c     |  1     | 4500 --sum of furniture and building
 1-2-1   | Furniture      |     t     |  1-2   | 1500
 1-2-2   | Building       |     t     |  1-2   | 3000
```

---

Transactional Table

---

```
ID |AccountID|Amount
---|---------|------
 1 | 1-1-1   |  300  
 2 | 1-1-1   |  700
 3 | 1-1-2   | 1500
 4 | 1-1-2   |  500
 5 | 1-2-1   |  700
 6 | 1-2-1   |  800
 7 | 1-2-2   | 2000
 8 | 1-2-2   | 1000
```

Any select statement if possible
or function or stored procedure.

Any help Will be appreciated

Comment: you need to show the structure of the other table you are pulling data from to get the balance and how you calculated the proper values.

Comment: One of the challenges of this type of query is that it's recursive which SQL in general is not good at. But since you're running in SQL Server take a look at CTEs (Common Table Expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 (Thanks asantaballa for diverting my concentration towards CTEs)

```
With TrialBalance(AccountID, ParentID, Balance)
AS
(
Select AccountId, ParentID, Balance From Accounts Where AccountType = 't'
Union All
Select A.AccountId, A.ParentID, T.Balance From Accounts A
Inner Join TrialBalance T On A.AccountId = T.ParentID
)
Select AccountID, SUM(Balance) From TrialBalance Group By AccountID
```

Method 2

```
Create Function AccountBalance(@AccountID Nvarchar(100))
Returns Float
AS
Begin
Declare @Balance Float
Select @Balance = Balance From Accounts Where AccountID = @AccountID
Select @Balance += Sum(dbo.AccountBalance(AccountID)) From Accounts
Where ParentID = @AccountID
Return @Balance
End

Select AccountID, dbo.AccountBalance(AccountID) From Accounts
```

Above both methods return desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it, however I did it with couple of update statements. 
Please note, that you havent provided any database structure, so I suppose you have 2 tables- one with the accounts and another with the Balances for the transactional Accounts:

```
create table #accounts (
AccountId int
,Title varchar(60)
,AccountType varchar(10)
,ParentID int
,Balance int
)
create table #transactional_accounts (
Id int
,AccountID int
,Amount int
)

insert into #accounts (AccountId, Title, AccountType,ParentID) values
..............
insert into #transactional_accounts values
........... 

 update #accounts
 set Balance= (select SUM(amount) from #transactional_accounts t2 where t1.AccountId= t2.AccountID  )
from #accounts t1
where AccountType ='t'


update #accounts
set Balance= case when t1.ParentID is not null then (select SUM(t2.Balance) from #accounts t2 where t1.AccountId=t2.ParentID)
          else (select SUM(t2.Balance) from #accounts t2)
          end
from #accounts t1
where AccountType ='c'

select * from #accounts
```

Comment: The first table in my question is a database table with data in it and second one is what I need a result set from that table with the help of a select statement or alternatives. Not to update the data in the database.